# What are the new displays associated with post notices?

Tags: support, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I noticed that the "**[on hold]**" reference has been deleted from questions that are closed as being unclear. Now only the word "**[closed]**" is written.

Are there other types of options with the new names for the questions? Are there others details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formed part of a bigger ["post notice update" that was rolled out 3 weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions/). The post notices now appear differently, depending on the viewer:

Closed notice – Post owner:

[image: closed post owner]

Closed notice – Users with 3,000+ reputation (the minimum requirement for the [vote to close/re-open privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)):

[image: closed high rep users]

Closed notice – Public view:

[image: closed public view]

> #### Where did the "On Hold" label go?
>
> "On Hold" had been used to label recently closed questions. The idea was that this language would imply less permanence to the current state than "Closed". However, user research showed that this distinction was generally found to be confusing to users at all levels, and did not seem to have an effect on reopen rates. So we have removed this label. All Closed posts are now labelled as Closed but only the label has changed. Edits within the first five days will still put the question in the reopen queue.

Reference:

[New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/168244)